# manual logging algorithm session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, session

i created my manual logging for my private page,
i have `UserInfoClass` that has `string username` and `int userID` instances.
this is my algorithm in my logging page:

```
if(_username and _pass == true)
{
     UserInfoClass obj;
     obj.username = _username
     HttpContext.Current.Session["myloginsession"] = obj
     HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 60
     Redirect to private page
}
```

and in my private

```
page_load()
{
    if(session["myloginsession"] != null)
    {
    //do something
    }
    else
    {
    redirect to logging page
    }

}
```

i have a problem with my session timeout, i set it to 60 minute but sometimes its not worked correctly and redirected to logging page. is it my algorithm have problem? does it have problem in security issue? please give me your idea about this algorithm.
thanks so much

Comment: You're not using the same `key` for your session object.  `Session["myloginsession"]` vs `session["LoginInfo"]`

Comment: @Matthew thanks, could you explain me something more?

Answer (score 1):

Your session keys aren't the same.

One is

```
"myloginsession"
```

the other is

```
"LoginInfo"
```

I would suggest making them the same.

Also, Timeout is not recommended to be longer than 20 minutes.

From the Microsoft API webpage

"Specifies the number of minutes that a session can remain idle before the server terminates it automatically. The default is 10 minutes. Session.Timeout has no hard-coded limit. Most Web administrators set this property to 8 minutes. ***It should not be set higher than 20 minutes (except in special cases)*** because every open session is holding onto memory. It should also not be set lower than 4 minutes because clients rarely respond within that time resulting in a loss of session state.
IIS 6.0: The minimum allowed value is 1 minute and the maximum is 1440 minutes."

Comment: Good catch, i missed that.

Comment: try resetting the Session key to true after 20 minutes, you shouldn't need to store it for the full 60 minutes, and you can keep renewing it when the first 20 minutes is up

Answer (score 0):

Compare logininfo to null.

```
page_load()
{
     if(session["LoginInfo"] != null)
     {
     //do something
     }
     else
     {
          redirect to logging page
     }

 }
```

Also, its probably best to put the session timeout in web.config.